# Youtube Analytics API - HTTP request for Associated Channel's data

Tags: google-oauth, youtube-analytics-api

I am new to YouTube Analytics API.

Could you please help me to retrieve data from my associated YouTube channel.

I have populated the data using “youtubeAnalytics.reports.query” in the APIs Explorer window.

But when I am trying to use the below HTTP request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3D{MY_ASSOCIATED_CHANNEL_ID}&start-date=2016-08-01&end-date=2016-08-31&metrics=views&dimensions=video&filters=video%3D%3D{MY_VIDEO_ID}&max-results=10&sort=-views&key={MY_API_KEY}
```

It shows an error message “Login Required”

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Could you please help me to correct my HTTP request to populate the data.

Thanks,
Aneesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know most all of the YouTube Analytics API is private data.  Being that its private data you need to be [authenticated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/registering_an_application) in order to access it.

Your error "Login Required" means exactly that you need to be authenticated to access the data you are requesting. Probably using the scope

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly

Once you have authenticated your application you can do  `access_token={Access token gotten from authentication}` in order to access that data.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the information, and it is working fine.

Now the issue is refreshing the access token .

I am using google app script to process the HTTP request.

Is there any app script is available to refresh the existing access token.

Thanks,
Aneesh